# How run a Query on an Element?

Tags: selenium, scalatest

#### Issue and how I would do it with the plain Selenium API

I often need to query an element on the page (say with `cssSelector().element`), use it, and then want to find a descendent element. With the plain Selenium API, I would write something like:

```scala
val foo = webDriver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".foo"))
val bar = foo.findElement(By.cssSelector(".bar"))
```

How can I do this with the ScalaTest Selenium DSL? I can get the "foo" element with:

```scala
val foo = cssSelector(".foo").element
```

But then how to get "bar" from "foo"? Of course, I could just use the Selenium API in that case (i.e. `val bar = foo.underlying.findElement(By.cssSelector(".bar"))`), but end up with a `WebElement` instead of a ScalaTest `Element`.

#### Workaround running another query

For now, I just run the query all over again, as shown below, but find this verbose, less clear, and not always equivalent to just looking for elements under an element.

```scala
val fooSelector = cssSelector(".foo")
val foo = fooSelector.element
val boo = cssSelector(fooSelector.queryString + " .bar").element
```

Answer (score 1):

The `cssSelector` method creates a `CssSelectorQuery` object. You can pass that object as an argument to the find method:

```scala
val foo = find(cssSelector(".foo")).get
```